# AWS CDK - Nested api gateway model validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

How do you use array/nested object models via aws-cdk?

I am trying to set the validation model via aws-cdk. I’ve confirmed the model below works via the AWS GUI:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "MainModel",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "OutterField": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "Firstfield": { "type": "string" },
                "Secondfield": { "type": "string" },
            },
            "required": ["Firstfield", "Secondfield"],
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "uniqueItems": true
        }
    }
},
"required": ["OutterField"],
 "additionalProperties": false
}
```

When trying to set up the model via aws-cdk, it’s not clear how to use an array or nested objects, here is what I have so far:

```
model = api.add_model("model",
                     content_type="application/json",
                     model_name="MainModel",
                     schema=apigw.JsonSchema(
                         schema=apigw.JsonSchemaVersion.DRAFT4,
                         title="MainModel",
                         type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.OBJECT,
                         properties={
                             "Firstfield": apigw.JsonSchema(type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.STRING),
                             "Secondfield": apigw.JsonSchema(type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.STRING)
                         },
                         required=["Firstfield", "Secondfield"]
                         )
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
model = api.add_model("model",
                 content_type="application/json",
                 model_name="MainModel",
                 schema=apigw.JsonSchema(
                     schema=apigw.JsonSchemaVersion.DRAFT4,
                     title="MainModel",
                     type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.OBJECT,
                     properties={
                         "Firstfield": apigw.JsonSchema(type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.STRING),
                         "Secondfield": apigw.JsonSchema(type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.STRING)
                         "Thirdfield": apigw.JsonSchema(
                            schema=apigw.JsonSchemaVersion.DRAFT4,
                            type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.OBJECT,
                            properties={
                               "nested1": apigw.JsonSchema(type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.STRING),
                               "nested2": apigw.JsonSchema(type=apigw.JsonSchemaType.STRING),
                            },
                            required=["nested1", "nested2"]
                         )
                     },
                     required=["Firstfield", "Secondfield"]
                     )
                 )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me with CDK v2, Typescript:

```
const ResponseModel = props.rootApi.dataApi.addModel(`${props.appEnv}-name-${props.apiVersion}`, {
    contentType: 'application/json',
    modelName: `ResponseModel${props.apiVersion}`,
    schema: {
        schema: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaVersion.DRAFT4,
        title: 'Response',
        type: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.ARRAY,
        properties: {
            items: {
                schema: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaVersion.DRAFT4,
                type: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.ARRAY,
                properties: {
                    startTimestamp: { type: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.STRING },
                    endTimestamp: { type: aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.STRING },
                    hours: { type: [aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.INTEGER, aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.NULL] },
                    watts: { type: [aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.NUMBER, aws_apigateway.JsonSchemaType.NULL] },
                },
                required: [
                    'startTimestamp',
                    'endTimestamp',
                    'hours',
                    'watts',
                ],
            },
        },
        required: ['items'],
    },
})
```

CDK Model Reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.Model.html